# WebLogic connection pool count increase

Tags: oracle, weblogic

let say if I want to increase connection pool counts in WebLogic data sources (max,min and initial) what things I have to concern on. does in need to check anything from DBMS side?
pls advice

Comment: any one pls help

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your DBA first because increasing the connection pool capacity will an impact on memory and cpu usage in the database's hosts